# Possible to assign count to array? like @content.$i?

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, scalar

my csv input file

```
Chapter,Content
A,1
B,3
C,1
C,2
C,3
D,5
```

My current perl script

```
open(INFILE,$input)||die "can't open the file";
@line = (split/,/,$_);
@line_last = (split/\n/,$line[1]);
    if ($_ =~ /A/){
        push @con1, $line[1];
}
elsif ($_ =~ /B/){
    push @con2, $line[1];
}
elsif ($_ =~ /C/){
    push @con3, $line[1];
}
elsif ($_ =~ /D/){
    push @con4, $line[1];
}
close INFILE;

chomp @con1, @con2, @con3, @con4;
print "content =", (join ", ", @con1),"\n";
print "content =", (join ", ", @con2),"\n";
print "content =", (join ", ", @con3),"\n";
print "content =", (join ", ", @con4),"\n";
```

My current code can work but I wanna make my code shorter & more efficient.
How do I make @con more automate? something like using For loop & use $i to assign to @con to make overall code shorter.

Comment: Can you supply a sample of what correct output looks like?  Also, $input is not declared anywhere so, this code wont run.  You're also (probably) missing a line like `while (<INFILE>) {` - without it $_ is not going to be defined and nothing is going to be in @line ...

Comment: $input = "testing.csv";

Output:
1
3
1,2,3
5

Comment: Typo <br/> I have $input & while (<INFILE>) in my script <br/>    $input = "testing.csv";

    while (<INFILE>){
    
Output:
1
3
1,2,3
5

Answer (score 3):

[Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

You should use an AoA instead.

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( ); 

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });

open my $fh, "<", $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my @foos = qw( A B C D );
my $num_eles = 0;
my %index_by_foo = map { $_ => $num_eles++ } @foos;
my @cons_by_foo = map { [] } 1..$num_eles;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
   if ( my $i = $index_by_foo{ $row->[0] } ) {
      push @{ $cons_by_foo[$i] }, $row->[1];
   }
}

for my $i (1..$num_eles-1) {
   print("content =", join(", ", @{ $cons_by_foo[$i] }), "\n");
}
```

That said, a HoA seems a far better fit.

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( ); 

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 });

open my $fh, "<", $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my %cons_by_foo;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
   push @{ $cons_by_foo{ $row->[0] } }, $row->[1];
}

for my $foo (sort keys %cons_by_foo) {
   print("content $foo =", join(", ", @{ $cons_by_foo{$foo} }), "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what a hash is great for IMO (hashtable or dictionary in other languages).

note: I haven't tested this code, it's from memory.

```
my %con;
while (<INFILE>)
{
    my @line_last = (split/\n/,$line[1]);
    $con{$line[0]} = $con{$line[0]} + ", " +  $line[1];
} 
foreach my $str (keys sort %con)
{
    print "content $con{$str}\n";
}
```

edit: much better and tested code here.

```
open(INFILE,"input.txt")||die "can't open the file";

my %con;
while (<INFILE>)
{
    next if /^Chapter/;
    chomp;
    my @line = (split ',' , $_);
    push @{$con{$line[0]}}, $line[1];
} 
foreach my $str (sort keys %con)
{
    my $tmp = join ', ', @{$con{$str}};
    print "content $str = $tmp\n";
}
```

output is:

```
content A = 1
content B = 3
content C = 1,2,3
content D = 5
```

I know that isn't your output, but it seems more useful than what you had.

Comment: That warns, and that causes spurious commas to appear in the output. /// I also think it's a bad idea to mix output code with input code. It makes it harder to modify the program (and lead directory to the second problem I mentioned).

Comment: Yours is certainly better Perl, and I'm not surprised that mine warns, I was too lazy to actually put it in Perl at home. I'm guessing it warns that $con{$line[0]} might be undefined or something? And yeah, I would probably never do this in production code, yours is much better.

Comment: yeah, undefined `$con{$line[0]}` the first time `$line[0]` is encountered

Comment: So, I'm new to SO. Since you have a better solution (and basically the same solution I would rewrite mine to be instead of hacking it together, a HoA), should I delete my answer or just edit to note that your answer is better and that a HoA is the way to go and I implemented it lazily?

Comment: In general, since I haven't had a chance to really look at either answer: if you think your answer adds something valuable that isn't in other answers, or if you can edit it to add something valuable, keep it around. If it doesn't add anything valuable, delete it. If all your answer does is say that another answer is the best solution, I don't think that's very valuable.

Comment: hi kchinger<br/>how about if i want to print out<br/>Chapter A
content = 1

Chapter B
content = 3

Chapter C
content = 1,2,3

Chapter D
content = 5

Comment: In Perl you can just throw variable names straight into a print statement mixed with literals as long as the default formatting is acceptable. So print "Chapter $str content = $tmp\n";.

Comment: Hi kchinger, your code really help a lot. I just modify a bit and it can produce the format i wanted. Many Thanks. :)

Comment: @user6201481 You're very welcome. If you feel that it was what you needed you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %cc;  #chapter contents
open my $FH, $filename or die "Cannot open $filename";
push @{ $cc{ $$_[0] } }, $$_[1] for map {chomp;[split/,/]} <$FH>;
close $FH;
print "Chapter = $_     Content = " . join(", ", @{ $cc{$_} }) . "\n" for sort keys %cc;
```

Output:

```
Chapter = A     Content = 1
Chapter = B     Content = 3
Chapter = C     Content = 1, 2, 3
Chapter = D     Content = 5
```